# Flutter iOS build failed after Flutter 1.22 upgrade

Tags: ios, flutter, revenuecat

I just upgraded my Flutter version to 1.22.0. After upgrading and making some changes for Firebase my Android app started working, but I am unable to build and run the iOS app on emulator or on physical device.

The terminal shows the following errors when I try to run the app in the emulator or physical device. The emulator runs on iOS 14 and the physical device is on 14.0.1.

```
Emulator: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
Actual device: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I also executed the following commands but still not working...

```
flutter clean && \
rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock && \
rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace && \ 
flutter run
```

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at /Volumes/demouser/Flutter/FlutterSDK/flutter
    • Framework revision d408d302e2 (7 days ago), 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
    • Engine revision 5babba6c4d
    • Dart version 2.10.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/demouserdemouser/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: demo
description: demo
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+2
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  firebase_storage: ^5.0.0-dev.2
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.10.0+1
  intl_translation: ^0.17.10+1
  http: ^0.12.2
  xml: ^4.5.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
  mlkit: ^0.15.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.2+1
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  url_launcher: ^5.7.2
  share: ^0.6.5+2
  simple_connectivity: ^0.1.1
  us_states: ^1.0.3
  cloud_functions: ^0.6.0+1
  email_validator: ^1.0.4
  package_info: ^0.4.3
  device_info: ^0.4.2+8
  expandable: ^4.1.4
  launch_review: ^2.0.0
  xml2json: ^4.4.0
  purchases_flutter: ^1.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "icon/new_icon.png"
  android: false
  ios: true
```

**Terminal's output:**

```
> Launching lib/main.dart on physical iPhone in debug mode...
> Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified
> development team in Xcode project: 5ABCDEFG9 Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                           118.3s
> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>     2020-10-06 10:59:58.676 xcodebuild[7528:47880]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from a578d1d6cb0d414525f7dc4c6cee was NULL
>     2020-10-06 10:59:58.778 xcodebuild[7528:47881]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from a578d1d6cb0d414525f7dc4c6cee was NULL
>     2020-10-06 10:59:58.778 xcodebuild[7528:47881]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from a578d1d6cb0d414525f7dc4c6cee was NULL
>     ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Volumes/driveD/Flutter/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.7.2/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:153:57: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                                           .keyWindow.rootViewController];
                                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/driveD/projects/new/demo/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/url_launcher/url_launcher-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:134:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));


   -------
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on physical’s iPhone.
```

It looks like this problem is coming due to RevenueCat API. When I comment out the import **purchases_flutter** in the **pubspec.yaml** file then I am able to install the app but it crashes at startup saying connection lost.

Comment: Could you show your flutter doctor, and pubspec.yaml file content?

Comment: Might also help this: `rm -f ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings`
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51992#issuecomment-596865108

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that but it is giving same error after that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after doing lot of changes, I found out that the culprit was the **purchases_flutter: ^1.3.1** package.

When I remove the package from my yaml file then it starts working. There is a bug already opened for it https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/issues/120.

Thank you every one for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

rm -f ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings fixed the issue for me

Comment: When I go to ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata there is no WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings file. There is only one file available which is IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different answers for this here on stackoverflow. If I am not mistaken, the switch to channel "stable" solved the issue for me, last time.

Comment: I thought to switch the channel too but then I realized I'm already on the stable channel.

Comment: I guess, you have already rebooted. This also still sometimes helps to fix (non) errors. Could this be caused by keyWindow, whatever that is? Have you tried some other app without keyWindow, whether that runs?

Comment: right now I am ignoring these issues as they are only warnings

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar erro
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Comment: Did you get any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

I also having problems after I upgrade to 1.22.0, I had to also upgrade the flutterFire package, and that seems to be my problem.

the versions that I'm using on pubspec.yaml:

```js
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+1
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.0
  cloud_functions: ^0.6.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.0+3 
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.2
```

when trying to run it says to update the CocoaPods spec by running `pod repo update`, done that, but still got the same error, then running `pod install` or `pod update` got the error
[image]

tried the commands: `pod install --repo-update` and `pod update Firebase/Storage` but still got the same error message

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Yes, the solutions for me was to deleted the podfile.lock, run flutter clean and run the app.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. For me it is still not working.. :-(

Comment: not sure if your problem is with the flutterFire, but later I found this migration guide https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration

Answer (score 0):

Just remove old flutter installed folder like [.cache] / [pub-cache] because you might have upgraded the flutter version but iOStools and other tools are pointing to older version and it causes these architecture issue.

Comment: Are you sure about this?